# Why did the kids throw their necklaces away?

Tags: meaning, music-video

In [the official music video of *Corazon* by Maluma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmHrjFIWl6U&ab_channel=MalumaVEVO) there is a kid first seen at 01:06 giving a necklace to another kid. the receiver becomes so happy and gives a smile to her. The kid continues giving necklaces to other kids throughout the video; all of them become happy and give smiles.

But near the end of the video, at 03:16, the receivers gather together and show their necklaces to the said kid; then the kid runs away and the other kids throw their necklaces away with poker faces.

What was the meaning of this act by the kids at the near end of the video?

The song is in Spanish. Perhaps it's said in the lyrics. But I'm not familiar with this language.

Comment: Music videos don't necessarily have a meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found an answer to my own question.
Perhaps the kids saw the necklaces in each other's hands and they realized that the gifter told the same thing to them when giving the necklace. For example, she said: "You are my best friend" to each of them.
Then, the other kids manage to confront the gifter to say her they know what she has done. She has said "you are my best friend" to all of them. So she can't be a reliable friend. Hence, they throw their necklaces away.